# Different compilation error when final local variable is used with while loop

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, final

Sample code:

Compilation error:

> The final local variable flag may already have been assigned

```
final boolean flag;
while (flag = false) { // I am using = instead of == just to test it
    System.out.println("inside loop");
}
```

Compilation error:

> Unreachable code

```
final boolean flag = false;
while (flag) {
    System.out.println("inside loop");
}
```

I know:

- The local variable must be initialized before its first use.
- As per the coding standard the final local variable must be initialized at the time of declaration.

Questions:

- What is the difference between these statements? As per my understanding both are same.
- Why first sample code doesn't talk about unreachable code. The second compilation error is clear to me.

---

If works fine with `if` condition

```
final boolean flag;
if (flag = false) { // no compilation error
    System.out.println("inside if block");
}
```

---

If works fine if I add a `break` statement in the `while` loop that ensures the compiler that the `final` local variable can be initialize just one in its life.

```
final boolean flag;
while (flag = false) {
    System.out.println("inside if block");
    break;
}
```

Comment: For your last case, it works because flag has not been assigned. If you change the line the first line to `final boolean flag = false`, it will no longer work

Comment: @Chip yes I know it, Can't assign value again for `final` variable.

Comment: So finally the conclusion is: *We can't assign final variable inside the loop*. Thanks to all for your valuable time.

Comment: That's not entirely true - you can if you have not assigned it before.

Comment: @user3218114-As i mentioned, that the initialisation of final variables take only once, so after adding `break`,compiler knows that this loop will run only once. So,it allows the same. I hope you got what you wanted!

Comment: @Chip we can if we add a `break` statement.

Comment: Yes I got it when I said Thanks to all.

Comment: Nice question though!

Comment: @user3218114 you don't need `break`. You just change the first line : `final boolean flag;` instead of `final boolean flag = false;`

Comment: @Chip I know about it. We can't assign value again for `final` variable once assigned. That's a different concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between these statements? As per my
>   understanding both are same.

How can both your codes be same??? In your first case, you are initialising your `flag` variable with false, so it will be assuming initailisation of `flag` variable with each iteration of loop (decision taken by compiler at compile-time as it doesn't know about the no. of iterations), **BUT IN REALITY THIS CODE WON'T BE EXECUTED EVER**---thereby treating it as a non-final variable, hence, contradiction, whereas in second case it also won't run as the flag has already been declared false at the declaration step only, **NOT INSIDE THE BODY OF LOOP**!!! So, the second one will be an infinite loop!

```
final boolean flag;
while (flag = false) {                   // First code---flag final variable initialised with each iteration
System.out.println("inside loop");
}

final boolean flag = false;
while (flag) {                          //  Second code
System.out.println("inside loop");
}
```

> Why first sample code doesn't talk about unreachable code. The second
>   compilation error is clear to me.

Because either of the compilation error is reported first. In this case, the first one is showing error related to `flag` variable incorrect declaration. As taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)):

> A final variable can only be initialized once, either via an
>   initializer or an assignment statement. It does not need to be
>   initialized at the point of declaration: this is called a "blank
>   final" variable. A blank final instance variable of a class must be
>   definitely assigned in every constructor of the class in which it is
>   declared; similarly, a blank final static variable must be definitely
>   assigned in a static initializer of the class in which it is declared;

Comment: *the first one is showing error related to flag variable incorrect declaration* what does it mean? where it is incorrectly declared?

Comment: Check my last paragraph taken from Wikipedia!

Comment: you are taking about `instance` blank `final` variable. I am talking about `local final` variable.

Comment: No,@user3218114- Your 1st loop is also an infinite loop,in this case `flag` being a final variable is always getting initialised at iteration of each loop---thereby throwing compilation error as to how this is possible!

Comment: why it's an infinite loop? I have initialized it to `false` The code inside the loop will never be reached.

Comment: Oh,SORRY! But,to assume that it runs as compiler don't know at compile-time whether it is gonna run how many times. It is done only at run-time!

Comment: but compiler knows in second case.

Comment: That's what I mentioned,compiler knows in second case---so giving `flag=false` initialisation only at the beginning of declaration! Not inside the body of the loop! Hence,it gives that code unreachable as it won't reach inside the loop ever because final variable declared earlier at declaration.I hope you got it!If not,feel free to extend the comments!

Comment: So finally the conclusion is: `We can't assign final variable inside the loop`.

Comment: just delete the above comment.

Answer (score 4):

Case 1:
'flag' is being assigned each time you iterate in 'while' loop. You are using assingment operator '=' instead '=='.

Case 2:
'flag' always is false, so code inside 'if' will never execute.

Comment: compiler knows about the value of `final` variable at compilation time then why it doesn't talk about unreachable code.

Comment: becaus 'flag = false' is a assingment, doen't return a boolean vaule, and 'if' statment needs a boolean value.

Comment: assignment statements return the assigned value in java

Comment: @user3218114 you can assign a value to a final variable only once. That's why your assignment in the while loop fails

Comment: You have the reason +1

Comment: In first case, As per my understanding compiler knows that `final` variable is initialized with `false` hence it should says unreachable code.

Comment: The compiler warns you about one violation. Its saying you are trying to assign a final variable multiple times (loop).

Comment: @user3218114 Logically, in the first case, to understand that the code is unreachable it has to first understand what flag=false means. While "understanding" this, it tells you immediately that flag = false is invalid because it is final and has been assigned once. That's why you get that error instead of unreachable code.

Comment: It means the compiler is not so smart that it can check the value of `final` variable at the time of compilation.

Comment: A compiler works in a number of phases. The phase to check unreachable code comes later than the assignment check. Generally in compilers, once a error has been detected, it does not continue the next phases. This, in general, reduces the number of errors and helps you solve your compilation error faster.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it seems that you are looking for why the first code does gives you a `The final local variable flag may already have been assigned` instead of `Unreachable error`.

This is because there are various stages of java compilation as detailed here : http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/doc/compilation-overview/

The expressions are evaluated in the first stage (**Attr** ). Flow Analysis is done only if there is no errors in the first stage. Since the illegal assignment was caught in the first stage, the second stage (**Flow**) will not get executed, and you will not get `Unreachable Error`

Comment: the answer is that `final` variable should be initialized just once. In case of `while` (without `break` statement) the compiler says *The final local variable flag may already have been assigned* because it may come back to condition in next iteration.